# Multiple line breaks in expression

Tags: r, expression

I need to add multiple line breaks but I am struggling with the atop function in `expression()` as I can only add one line break:

```
main=expression(atop("Fig. 3. Total yearly diffuse attenuation coefficient at","490 nm (K"[d]*") and chlorophyll concentration at 3 coral reef sites between 2003 and 2012")
```

Comment: Does `expression( atop( "a", atop( "b", "c" ) ) )` work?

Comment: it does but the text becomes increasingly small in size. is there an alternative to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround is to use `textstyle` to draw in normal size:

```
plot(1,1,main=expression(
  atop(textstyle("a"),
    atop(textstyle("b"),
         textstyle("c")
    )
  )
))
```

A maybe clearer solution is to use `mtext` several times, once for each line:

```
plot(1,1)
mtext(expression(bold("Fig. 3. Total yearly diffuse attenuation coefficient")), line=3)
mtext(expression(bold("at 490 nm (K"[d]*") and chlorophyll concentration")), line=1.9)
mtext(expression(bold("at 3 coral reef sites between 2003 and 2012")), line=1)
```

Note that in the second line I used `line=1.9` to correct a little bit the interspacing because of the subscript:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for fixed the vertical positioning issue. The other point to notice is that the quotes are not needed in those `expression` arguments